# constructor Thread in class Thread cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, java-threads

Why it shows error as i am doing it from "head first with java" book. This is the code I have used:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;


public class mallu{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable threadJob = new MyRunnable();
        Thread myThread = new Thread(threadJob);
        myThread.start();
        System.out.println("back in main");

    }
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        go();
    }

    public void go(){
        doMore();
    }

    public void doMore(){
        System.out.println("top o' the stack");
    }
}
```

And this is the error I am getting.

---

```
./Thread.java:14: error: duplicate class: MyRunnable
class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
^
mallu.java:8: error: constructor Thread in class Thread cannot be applied to given types;
        Thread myThread = new Thread(threadJob);
                          ^
  required: no arguments
  found: Runnable
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
mallu.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        myThread.start();
                ^
  symbol:   method start()
  location: variable myThread of type Thread
./Thread.java:7: error: constructor Thread in class Thread cannot be applied to given types;
        Thread myThread = new Thread(threadJob);
                          ^
  required: no arguments
  found: Runnable
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
./Thread.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        myThread.start();
                ^
  symbol:   method start()
  location: variable myThread of type Thread
5 errors
```

I cannot figure out why this error is happening. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you already have another class with same as MyRunnable.

Comment: There is no problem with your code, i tested it and it's working fine. You probably have a conflicting Thread class, if there are any classes called Thread in your project remove or rename them.

Answer (score 1):

```
./Thread.java:14: error: duplicate class: MyRunnable
```

In your project looks like you have multiple class name **MyRunnable**

To resolve this change you class name from **MyRunnable**  to some other class name.
See the result: [Your code](https://repl.it/repls/MuddyHummingAggregators)

Read [Java: "duplicate class" and Mismatched File Name Error](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2010/02/java-duplicate-class-and-mismatched.html)